# Set variables in a global place, then every `.tpl` files can access?

Tags: php, smarty

When I create a `index.php` in Smarty project:

```
require_once('smarty.php');

$smarty->assign('pj_client_id', '12345543');
$smarty->assign('pj_client_secret', 'wedfasd1245');

$smarty->display('index.tpl');
```

you see I assign the `pj_client_id` and `pj_client_secret` to it, then I can use them in `index.tpl`. if I want to use them in other `.tpl` files, I must assign in other `.tpl` corresponding php files.

But whether I can set in a global place, then every `.tpl` files can access?

Comment: No that is not possible with smarty by default. You'd have to write a custom plugin to have global variables as described here: https://www.smarty.net/forums/viewtopic.php?p=54634

Answer (score 0):

You can assign them in some "global" file, that included in every page (for example `smarty.php` - as I saw above), or some other include-file. You can even create a new file like `globals.php` and do `$smarty->assign()` there (for more logical usability).

But, obviously, you must create a new object `$smarty` before assigning all vars.